# How do I implement a web linked button that will open inside of my iphone application (not open a link in Safari?

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an iphone sdk application and want to tweak it.. as I've had a great idea on how I want my interface to appear.

I'm trying to create several buttons that will open a web page within my application but have failed to do so countless amounts of times now.

(I don't want the button to open a link in safari, I already know how to do this and it's not what I'm trying to achieve)

The application must not shut down in order to operate any links (i.e close down to open the link in safari as stated above.)

MORE INFO-----------------------------------

i already have the application and yes it is working and complete, however a while ago i decided that id like to change the interface on my application, but havnt been successful in doing so.

Currently i am using a webView based app which works perfectly, i have my website and another within the application (using a tab bar with two tabs within it).

Now i would like to completely re-model my app by starting from scratch..

using a uiwebview i want to place several buttons on the uiwebview page and have them as links which will direct my members to different sections of my website when pressed..

I have managed to do this but when the buttons are pressed, my application is closed and the link is then opened in safari, which is not what i want.

I would like the links to open within my application

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to provide more detail about what you want and why UIWebview won't work. Given the information you've currently provided, UIWebview is what you want. It will open a webpage in the view of your choosing. You should explain why this will not work for you so we can help you find other options.

Answer (score 0):

(Since you never received an answer...)

`UIWebView` was replaced by `WKWebView`

> WKWebView replaces the UIWebView class in iOS 8 and later, and it replaces the WebView class in macOS 10.10 and later.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

More recently, Apple added several modes for browser-experience integration via "Safari Services"

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/